# How to generate a pop up without the address/title bar on clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this email campaign running which sends out a link to the subscribed users which opens up a pop up window(with the url) giving away a code which the users can use to avail discounts. The url can be copied thus generating another code which can be misused. Is there a way to generate a pop up without the address/title bar for IE,Chrome,Mozilla ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that any given browser will support it or that the implementation will be consistent across browsers.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicate that the location option should control whether or not the Location/Address bar is shown. It should also have relatively good cross-browser support.

This [LINK](http://saher42.wordpress.com/2006/08/10/hiding-the-address-bar-on-pageload-using-javascript/) also helps you in hiding address bar.